# Linear function axis scaling in R

Tags: r, axis, scaling

I have the following function

```
C=15
S=seq(0,12,.1)
pA=1
pS=0.5

    
    A <- function(S) (C/pA)-(pA/pS)*S
    
    plot (S, A(S), type="l", col="red", ylim=c(0,15), xlim=c(0,15), xlab="S", ylab="A")
    text(8, 11.5, "Function", col = "red", cex=.9)
    text(11, 10.2, expression(A==frac(C,p[S])-frac(p[A],p[S])%.%S), cex=.9, col = "red")
    grid()
```

How can I scale the axis so that I can "zoom out" a bit. I am looking for a function similar to ylim but where I could say: ylim=c(0,15, by=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

It seems your "zoom out" is meant for the grid lines, not for the axis or anything. I'll keep the previous answer below, but this should address it, I think.

```r
# no change yet
plot (S, A(S), type="l", col="red", ylim=c(0,15), xlim=c(0,15), xlab="S", ylab="A")
text(8, 11.5, "Function", col = "red", cex=.9)
text(11, 10.2, expression(A==frac(C,p[S])-frac(p[A],p[S])%.%S), cex=.9, col = "red")
# no call to grid, since we want to control it a little more precisely
abline(h = seq(0, 15), col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted", lwd = par("lwd"))
abline(v = seq(0, 15, by = 5), col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted", lwd = par("lwd"))
```

[image: plot with grid lines more precisely defined]

You can do *just* `abline(h=seq(...))` and not set `col=`, `lty=`, or `lwd=`, but realize that `abline`'s default values are different from `grid`'s defaults. I used those values to mimic `grid`'s look and feel.

---

#### Old answer

I think you mean to change the y axis *labels*, not the y axis *limits* (which is all that `ylim=` can effect).

Using base R graphics:

```r
plot (S, A(S), type="l", col="red", ylim=c(0,15), xlim=c(0,15), xlab="S", ylab="A",
      yaxt = "n") # this is new
text(8, 11.5, "Function", col = "red", cex=.9)
text(11, 10.2, expression(A==frac(C,p[S])-frac(p[A],p[S])%.%S), cex=.9, col = "red")
grid()
axis(2, at = 1:15, las = 2)
```

[image]

Explanation:

- `plot(..., yaxt = "n")` means to *not* plot the y-axis ticks and labels, see [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html).
- `axis(...)` adds an axis to a side. By itself, it will just add a default axis.
- `at=` sets *where* the ticks and labels are placed.
- `labels=` sets *what* to put at each tick. If absent (like it is above), it just prints the `at` value.
- `las=2` rotates the number so that it is perpendicular to the axis line. I did this to show more of the numbers, otherwise they will mask a bit more.

While this shows every-other, that is affected by the size of the canvas; if you do the same plot in full-screen, it'll show every number.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, which was very helpful! I have probably not expressed myself very clearly. Another "problem" that I have are the big squares when I show the grid(). Is it possible to make them "smaller" in the sense that the grid lines correspond to the x- and y-values? I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Have you read [`?grid`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/grid.html)? It has `nx=` and `ny=` arguments to change how the lines are defined. If you want to be more specific about precisely *where* the lines are placed (instead of *how many*), then look at the source for `grid` and notice that it uses [`abline`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html), which makes full-height/width vertical/horizontal lines quite easily.

Comment: I think I understand now. You said `ylim=` which has nothing to do with `grid()`.

Comment: See my edit, I think that may be what you're asking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Now it's perfect. Thank you so much for your help. I am still new to R and I am trying to learn as much as possible. I am sorry if my questions was not clear enough.